# Как выбрать падеж местоимения при отрицании: что или чего, это или этого?

Tags: грамотная-речь

У Розенталя эта тема рассматривается, но там **нет примеров с местоимениями.**   [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Какие факторы действуют при выборе падежа в этом случае? Надо ли учитывать согласование: то...что, того...чего? И стиль речи влияет на выбор? У Розенталя Р.п. соответствует книжному стилю, а для местоимений это верно?

Примеры

**Это** не покажут по ТВ ! **То, чего** не покажут по ТВ. **То, что** никогда не покажут по телевизору! (здесь усиленное отрицание, но  выбран  В.п.).

**Что** не показывают по телевизору ― **то** плохо, или, что еще страшнее, совсем никак. [Софья Тарасова. Синдром усталости души? // «Знание-сила», 2013]

Есть ли в приведенных примерах явно некорректные или разговорные варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По мнению **Граммы ру,** "грамматической разницы между конструкциями типа  **то, чего не покажут по ТВ и то, что не покажут по ТВ нет.** Однако есть разница **стилистическая:** Р. п. (то, чего) *выбирает носитель настоящей культуры речи, а В. п. (то, что) -- тот, кто о ней не задумывается и привычно использует готовый модуль. Тем более что норма как будто разрешает в этом случае колебание, однако вариант с родительным падежом оценивается как предпочтительный"..*

Answer (score 0):

**Отвечаю на вечный вопрос** (правда, немного в стороне от самого вопроса).

**Итак, мы выбираем:** Ты вспомнишь то, **что** по сути никогда не чувствовал. - Ты вспомнишь то, **чего** по сути никогда не чувствовал.

Правильно: **Ты вспомнишь то, чего по сути никогда не чувствовал.**

И разница здесь не стилистическая, а грамматическая, и колебаться не стоит, а надо очень тщательно выбирать ***то, что*** или ***то, чего***.

**Во-первых, надо отличать союз ЧТО от союзного слова ЧТО.** Сравнить: Ты вспомнишь то, что по сути никогда  не чувствовал жизни, а воспринимал ее только разумом. Это союз ЧТО.

**Во-вторых, надо различать субъектное ЧТО и объектное ЧЕГО**,  вот здесь как раз и делается большинство ошибок.

Иногда их **трудно различить по смыслу** (пример из Интернета):

1) Они вечно советуют мне делать то, **чего** я не хочу. ЧЕГО ― дополнение.

2) Они вечно предлагают сделать то, **что** мне не нравится. ЧТО ― подлежащее.

Иногда **похожие конструкции не различаются автором** по невнимательности, например:

И увидит там то, **что** не дано узреть даже камер-юнкеру Теплову? [Игорь Золотусский. «Записки сумасшедшего» и «Записки из подполья» // «Октябрь», 2002]  Здесь должно быть **дополнение ЧЕГО,** предложение безличное.

**Примеры:**

1) ...то в нас, **что** нам не принадлежит, **что** отдано другим, ― мысль и любовь. [О. В. Аронсон. Коммуникативный образ. Кино. Литература. Философия. Ч. I (2007)]

2) Может быть, даже в моем водевиле есть такое, **чего** нам не видно, а другие увидят… [А. П. Чехов. Водевиль (1884-1885)]