# Что или Чего? – вечный вопрос

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, лексикография

Ты вспомнишь то, что по сути никогда не чувствовал.
Ты вспомнишь то, чего по сути никогда не чувствовал.

Так "что" или "чего"?

Comment: *Время пошло.* — В каком смысле?

Comment: Денис желает сыграть с вами в игру.

Comment: А, ну тогда лучше поудалять всякие глупости. Полезнее было бы научиться пользоваться поиском, особенно для "вечных вопросов".

Comment: Непонятно, почему вопрос закрыт, да еще так поспешно.С одной стороны, Грамота.ру посоветовала ГРАМОТНЫМ носителям использовать Р.п. (простое такое  решение), но ведь у Розенталя в этой теме даются конкретные рекомендации ПО ВЫБОРУ Р.п или В.п., в ряде случаев Р.п. не подходит. Поэтому  каждый заданный  вопрос должен рассматриваться и должны даваться обоснованные рекомендации .

Comment: Я не считаю, что на этот вопрос был дан обоснованный ответ, я не вижу там никаких объяснений, поэтому это мнение, а не ответ.

Comment: @Jasmin может быть, есть смысл дать ответ на вопрос, который был задан ранее? Или же лучше переоткрыть этот вопрос?

Comment: @ Денис Федоров  Посмотрите ответ на  Ваш вопрос по указанной ссылке https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440557/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE