# Как правильно: "ЧТО нельзя делать" или "ЧЕГО нельзя делать"?

Tags: падежи, управление

В интернете встречаю оба варианта. Может, оба правильные?

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440557/Как-выбрать-падеж-местоимения-при-отрицании-что-или-чего-это-или-этого

Answer (score 1):

Ни один из вариантов нельзя назвать неправильным. Можно говорить только о предпочтении одного другому.

Розентаь [пишет](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm):

> При переходных глаголах с отрицанием в одних случаях явно преобладает употребление родительного падежа дополнения, в других – употребление винительного падежа, в третьих – наблюдается факультативное их использование.

И еще там же:

> Факультативное употребление родительного и винительного падежа при переходном глаголе с отрицанием связано со стилистическим различием: конструкции с родительным падежом характерны для книжной речи, конструкции с винительным падежом – для речи разговорной. Ср.: Я не умаляю чьих-либо заслуг... (Горький). – Так и умрешь, не выговорив это слово (он же).

По-моему, в данном случае предпочтителен вариант с винительным падежом. Рознеталь:

> 2. Винительный падеж, ослабляющий значение отрицания, обычно употребляется в следующих случаях:
>      3) нередко при инверсии дополнения (постановке его впереди глагола-сказуемого), например: Журнал я этот не люблю (Тургенев); ...Дверь не притворяла (Достоевский); Кулаком правду не убьешь (Горький); Трактор им не дали (Шолохов);
>      12) обычно в конструкции «не + вспомогательный глагол + инфинитив переходного глагола + дополнение» (т.е. при отнесении дополнения не непосредственно к глаголу с отрицанием, а к инфинитиву, зависящему от глагола с отрицанием, что ослабляет влияние отрицания): не мог представить рукопись, не надеялся выполнить задание. Например: Старик Лаврецкий долго не мог простить сыну его свадьбу (Тургенев); ...Он не мог сдержать улыбку (он же); ...Он не решался сообщить матери и Оле правду о своем несчастье (Б. Полевой).